# Need help in if/else batch statements

Tags: batch-file

im a beginner batch programmer and i need help with the if/else syntax.
I need someone to correct the code and tell me the things im doing wrong.

```
@ECHO OFF
echo Here are some supplies if you want to go to where ever you were going. Which class will you pick? Warrior, Mage or Scout?
set "class="
set /p class=
if not defined class goto classGet
if "%class%"=="Warrior"(
echo Here are your %class% items.
pause
) if "%class%"=="Mage" (
echo Here are your %class% items.
pause
) if "%class%"=="Scout" (
echo Here are your %class% items.
pause
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
:classGet
echo Here are some supplies if you want to go to where ever you were going.
echo Which class will you pick?
set "class="
set /p "class= Warrior, Mage or Scout? "
if not defined class goto :classGet

if /i "%class%"=="Warrior" (
echo Here are your %class% items.
goto :classChoosen
pause
)
if /i "%class%"=="Mage" (
echo Here are your %class% items.
goto :classChoosen
pause
)
if /i "%class%"=="Scout" (
echo Here are your %class% items.
goto :classChoosen
pause
)

goto :classGet
:classChoosen
echo go on...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if "%class%"=="Warrior"(
```

space before `(` is required.

```
) if "%class%"=="Mage" (
```

This would be interpreted as continuation of the previous `if` and batch would expect an `else` here.

Code as

```
) 
if "%class%"=="Mage" (
```

The newline is important.